# Change magento theme but home page shows old theme

Tags: magento-1.9, template, theme

I am strucked in a strange issue. I change my website theme, all internal pages showing in new theme but Home page still showing old theme.
Well I am working on it since more than 2 hours but not resolved it.

I clear cache etc but not solving my problem.
Just want to know if there some other options in magento  to change theme template for home page.

Yes I am new in magento 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well at last I found what mistake I have done when this issue occurred.

giving answer by myself may it help others.

In CMS>Pages>Home Page find tab "Design" 
you can see "Custom Theme" I selected "base" theme there for it always show base theme for home page even I change any theme for my website from design.
[image]

Hope this will save someone time.